# $x+y$ is closed or discrete map

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Is not the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=x+y$ a closed map? And will not the image of any discrete set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be discrete?

I think it should be a closed map and that the image of any discrete set under $f$ must be discrete. Since $f$ is continuous and surjective, therefore, I think it must also take closed sets to closed sets. The portion concerning discrete sets seems obvious I think. Am I wrong? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: how do you say that from $f$ being continuous and onto, $f$ is closed?

Comment: @Alessandro that was just a guess. I see that need not be the case.

Comment: ok, have you tried to prove that $f$ maps open sets into opens?

Comment: @Alessandro well, that should be easy. This is because, addition is a continuous operator, and the function is nothing but addition of two open functions-the projection onto $x$ and $y$ axes- hence the final map should be open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set 
$$\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R\mid y\in \Bbb Z, y\ge1, xy\in\Bbb Z\,\}$$
is closed and discrete, but its image under $+$ is $\Bbb Q$ (noting that to obtain $\frac ab$ with $a\in\Bbb Z$, $b\in\Bbb Z_{>0}$, we can take $x=\frac ab-b$ and $y=b$).